# Include other files into excel template

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a xls that generates word documents from doc templates.
I'm storing the doc templates into the same folder as the xls.
to move the xls (and have it work), i need to move all the other files too.
is there a way to have just 1 xls file that includes all the others??

I might be missing something... I cannot manually save the embedded object externally. when i double click on the object the word ribbons and the save icon appear , but I can't find the "save as" anywhere.

thx in advance

Comment: [You could try this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/attach-a-file-in-xlsx/c681e456-2dd1-4715-8703-422d98e2580e?auth=1)

Comment: that attaches doc and other files to the workbook! But how do I modify the object and save it externally?

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a Word Doc as an object in Excel, following [this example](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/attach-a-file-in-xlsx/c681e456-2dd1-4715-8703-422d98e2580e?auth=1).

Once that's done you can manipulate it like this

```
Sub Demp()
    ' Add a reference to Microsoft Word Object Library,
    '  or convert to late binding
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document

    Dim ole As OLEObject
    Dim EmbededFile As String

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NameOfSheetWithEmbeddedObjects")

    ' Change to suit your needs, or build with code
    EmbededFile = "c:\Data\temp\TestDoc1.docx"

    ' Change Object Names to suit your needs
    Set ole = ws.OLEObjects("Object 1")
    'ole.Activate
    ole.Verb Verb:=xlOpen
    Set wdApp = ole.Object.Application
    With wdApp.ActiveDocument
        .SaveAs EmbededFile, Word.wdFormatDocumentDefault
        .Close

    End With
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(EmbededFile)

    ' you can now manipulate the Word App (using wdApp) and document (using wdDoc)
End Sub
```

Comment: it gives me runtime error 4605.
the object activates, and i put a msgbox before SaveAs and it is shown, but not the one after

Comment: On retesting, I found that it only works if the document is embedded with the "Display as Icon" option selected.

Comment: Or if you don't want to use Display as Icon, Change `ole.Activate` to `ole.Verb Verb:=xlOpen`

Comment: with the icon and ole.activate or without the icon and with ole.verb  Verb:=xlOpen, i get runtime error 5156 Application-defined or object-defined  error. It stops at .saveas
by the way, the document is a 97-2003 doc (I already changed EmbedFile). I also tried with a docx, still not working

Comment: That error seems to relate to folder permissions - are you sure you have write permission for the target folder?  I have tested on Excel 365 on Windows 10 and 2010 on Windows 7.  Using DocX word file.  What are your versions?

Comment: Just tried using 97-2003 file - works.  Tired to write to folder without write permission - failed with error 5166.  So you need to make sure you have write permissions.

Comment: you are right! it was a problem with permissions, I changed the save path and it now works. Thanks a lot